# VM instance down suddenly and fail to restart, showing 'serviceAccount' was not found

Tags: ssh, virtual-machines, google-compute-engine, service-accounts

I have a Django server running in VM instance, the server working fine before this, but this morning the server was unable to access. So I tried to SSH into the VM instance, but it took a long time and shows an error that SSH can't be connected.

I then tried to restart the VM instance by "stopping" the VM instance in GCP, then "start" it back up. But it can't be started and shows this error.

> Start VM instance "earthent"
> The resource '755754197401-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com' of type 'serviceAccount' was not found.

---

I also noticed that some of my other VM instances have the same error, but it is weird most of the VM instances in the same GCP just working fine.

Reference [The defails of VM instance](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TTuNz.png)

Answer (score 1):

This error looks like you've deleted in some way`Compute Engine default service account`. Please go to `IAM & Admin` -> `Service Accounts` and check if you still have service account with name `Compute Engine default service account`.

**To solve this issue** follow instructions [Undeleting a service account](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-managing-service-accounts#undeleting):

> In some cases, you can use the undelete command to undelete a deleted
> service account. You can usually undelete a deleted service account if
> it meets these criteria:
>
> - **The service account was deleted less than 30 days ago.**
>
> After 30 days, Cloud IAM permanently removes the service account.
> Google Cloud cannot recover the service account after it is
> permanently removed, even if you file a support request.

Also, you can try to reach [Google Cloud Support](https://cloud.google.com/support) for further instructions.